# How to use lodash replace to change the input pattern dynamically, for example Credit card number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am using following code snippet :

```
_.replace('123456', /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}/, '0000-0000-0000-0000');
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean change the regular expression dynamically? http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

Comment: yes, need to change the regex dynamically. when the condition changes